# Shiny Adjusting Button Position in side bar

Tags: r, shiny

I am using Shiny Dashboard to try and learning it

I have created the script below (removed somethings due to confidentiality) which gives selection criteria date, country and a process button with a download button next to it

Unfortunately the process button isn't really centered under the other the other objects. Is there a method that i can push the process button a couple of pixels to the right?

```
library(shinydashboard)
header <- dashboardHeader(title = "Some Header")

sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(br(),title = "Selection Options",
                        uiOutput("choose_daterange"),
                        uiOutput("choose_ctry"),
                        br(),
                        actionButton("run_report", "Process", icon =    icon("refresh")),
                        actionButton("download", "Download", icon = icon("download"))
) 



body <- dashboardBody("Hello World")


# Pulling it all together
dashboardPage(
 skin = "yellow",
  header,
  sidebar,
  body
)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try adding html style tags to your code:

```
sidebar <- dashboardSidebar(br(),title = "Selection Options",
                            uiOutput("choose_daterange"),
                            uiOutput("choose_ctry"),
                            br(),
                            actionButton("run_report", "Process", icon = icon("refresh")),
                            actionButton("download", "Download", icon = icon("download")),
                            tags$style(type='text/css', "#run_report { width:50%; margin-left: 5px;}")

)
```

You can adjust the width to make sure the buttons are of equal length/width

Comment: Thank you so much. Do you know of any material i could use to read up on the HTML side of shiny?

Comment: np! There are some tutorials http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/html-tags.html https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/tag-glossary.html but most of the useful tricks I learned right here :)